# Correct way for creating cgal-swig-bindings with Python3

Tags: python-3.x, cmake, swig, cgal

I would like to use cgal-swig-bindings with Python3 and would like to know how to change the installation process correctly so things will work with Python3. I got this to work, but there is likely a better way to achieve this goal. (I have no experience with Swig or boost.)

I was following the installation instructions for cgal-swig-bindings: https://github.com/CGAL/cgal-swig-bindings/wiki/Installation
on an Ubuntu machine.

I got things to work so that cgal-swig-bindings/examples/python/triangulation_prog1.py would run using default python2.7.

When running with Python3 I got:

```
dynamic module does not define module export function
```

I managed to hack around it by changing cgal-swig-bindings/CMakeLists.txt to include:

```
SET(PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH /usr/include/python3.5m)
SET(PYTHON_LIBRARIES /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so)
SET(PYTHON_EXECUTABLE /usr/bin/python3.5m)
SET(PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR  /usr/include/python3.5m)
SET(Python_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS 3.5)
FIND_PACKAGE(PythonInterp 3 REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(PythonLibs 3 REQUIRED)
```

Just using:

```
FIND_PACKAGE(PythonInterp 3 REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(PythonLibs 3 REQUIRED)
```

was not enough.

Running cmake and make again made things work for Python3 (and now Python2 is failing which is OK for me). I.e., triangulation_prog1.py can be run with Python3.

I used the following cmake command:

```
cmake -DCGAL_DIR=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/CGAL -DBUILD_JAVA=OFF -DPYTHON_OUTDIR_PREFIX=../../examples/python ../..
```

Is there a better way to enable Python3 support? Perhaps, by using some command line parameters on cmake?

Comment: `-DPython_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS=3` on the command line works for me without patching anything.

Comment: @MarcGlisse, many thanks for confirming! Maybe it is an issue with my cmake version then. (I could not fully verify now since things seem to work after the initially patched build, even without the patch and I am likely missing some parts to clean out in order to revert to the initial non-working state.)